# Angular2+ Default Select Option

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I can't get my dropdown list to render the default option on load

Here's the HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]=state name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state">{{ state.name }}</option>
</select>
```

and the component looks like so:

```
state = { abbr: "AL", name: "Alabama"}
states = [
{ abbr: "AL", name: "Alabama"},
{ abbr: "AK", name: "Alaska"},
{ abbr: "AS", name: "American Samoa"}
...
]
```

Comment: Just replace the `state` variable initialization with `state = states[0];` after `states` variable. You are creating separate object which will not equate while initialization for `state`

Comment: @KamalSingh Post this as an answer

Comment: Added the above comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, your [(ngModel)] is missing double quotes, it should be [(ngModel)]="state"

Also you just need to set the value of state in your component to what ever you want the default value to be. If you want your default value to be Minnesota, you can do it this way.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="state" name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state.abbr">{{ state.name }}
</option>
</select>
```

and then in your component....

```
this.state = 'MN';
```

or if you don't want to go off one of the state object properties, then you can go off the first object in the array by using the index like what @KamalSingh mentioned. So in your component you would put...

```
this.state = this.states[0]
```

Comment: Only curiosity, why do you use state as ngModel and ngValue? it's not better use state.abbr?. If you use state you're using an Object, and two  Objects are equals only what they are the same object (not when have the same properties). It's the reason because you must equal to this.states[0] if use an Object

Comment: I used ngModel as state just because of the code provided. If it were my code I would set the ngModel to something like "selectedState" and set the ngValue to the abbreviation so then I can set the default value based on the  states abbreviation. I tend to not set ngValue to an object just because there are several ways that could go wrong, like if in your object the property type is number, but you set your ngModel to a string. Hope that answers your question, if not I can clarify.

Comment: Derek, my question was for @Andrew, sorry, my question should be in a comment above, thanks for answering in any case

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `state` variable initialization with `state = this.states[0];` after `states` variable. You are creating separate object which will not equate to `states[0]` while initialization for `state`. Means both `states[0]` and `state` are different objects in your code snippet.

Now your code should look like in your component (.ts) file:

```
states = [
    { abbr: "AL", name: "Alabama"},
    { abbr: "AK", name: "Alaska"},
    { abbr: "AS", name: "American Samoa"}
];
state = this.states[0];
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Was the solution helpful to you?